# can I draw to mac's desktop nsview/calayer?

Tags: macos

Im assuming that mac's desktop images are using some kind of nsview/calayer, is there any way to get access to this? I wish to set the layer as an opengl view so I can animate the desktop, an example of someone doing this is nerdtool http://mutablecode.com/apps/nerdtool.html, setting the desktop with a quartz layer.

I cant seem find find any api on this other than the nsworkspace desktopImageURLForScreen: method, can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

worked it out, just needed to change window level:
[self.window setLevel:kCGDesktopWindowLevel];